# android intent service in loop

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I want to send data to **server** using **intent service**. What I have done is I start the intent service and in that class I take the data from local db and in a for loop I send the data to the server. It works. But my question is ,should I use for loop to start the intent service i.e. for example

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        Intent startService = new Intent(context, SampleService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, startService);
}

}
```

I am using an alarm manager to trigger the service. What is the correct way? please help. Thanks! . This is my code `    public class ScheduleAlarmReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

```
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
final int REQUEST_CODE=10;
SessionManager manager;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    manager=new SessionManager(context);

        Log.e("ScheduleAlarmReceiver","New intent");
        Log.e("ScheduleAlarmReceiver","Service is set");
        Intent startService = new Intent(context, SampleService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, startService);

}

public void setAlarm(Context context){

    Intent intent=new Intent(context,ScheduleAlarmReciever.class);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,REQUEST_CODE,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long firstMillis=System.currentTimeMillis();
    long INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS=2*60*1000; //two minutes interval
    alarmManager= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,firstMillis,INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS,pendingIntent);

}
```

}
`this is how i am setting the alarm`    alarmReciever.setAlarm(MainActivity.this);`and this is my intent service class`    public class SampleService extends IntentService{
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient;
    DbUtil dbUtil;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    int id=1;

```
public static final String API="http://customer-data.com/api/insertblevital";
public SampleService() {
    super("sampleservice");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    asyncHttpClient=new SyncHttpClient();
    dbUtil=DbUtil.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if(0!=dbUtil.getAllData().size()) {

        mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        mBuilder.setContentText("Uploading data")
                .setContentTitle("Sample Upload")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
        notificationManager.notify(id,mBuilder.build());
        for(int i=0;i<dbUtil.getAllData().size();i++){
            Log.e("Sample email",dbUtil.getAllData().get(i).getEmail());
        }
        ArrayList<Sample> sampleArrayList = dbUtil.getAllData();

        for (Sample sample : sampleArrayList) {


            postData(sample);
        }
        mBuilder.setContentText("upload Complete");
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        notificationManager.notify(id,mBuilder.build());
    }
}

public void postData(Sample sample){
    RequestParams requestParams=new RequestParams();
    requestParams.add("email",sample.getEmail());
    requestParams.add("Name",sample.getName());
    requestParams.add("Height",sample.getHeight());
    requestParams.add("Gender",sample.getGender());

    asyncHttpClient.post(API,requestParams,new PostResponseHandler(sample.getEmail()));
}

public class PostResponseHandler extends TextHttpResponseHandler{

    String email;

    public PostResponseHandler(String email){
        this.email=email;
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        Log.e("failure","failure");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {

        Log.e("responseString",responseString);
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        stringArrayList.add(email);
        dbUtil.UpdateFlag(stringArrayList);
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Why are you using a for loop when the alarm is fired and returns to onReceive();? Your example makes no sense... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: all i want to do is send chunk of data to server in the background after a specific period of time. i don't know that should i use multiple intent services that will run or should i use asynchttp inside one intent service.

Comment: An `IntentService` is specifically designed to run in its own worker thread, so anything that is run in `onHandleIntent()` will be Asynchronous, if you call your intent service multiple times it will queue the requests.  If you want to run multiple tasks in the `IntentService` in parallel then you'll need a `ThreadPool` or `AsyncTask` with an `Executor`

Comment: @MarkKeen"if you call you intent service multiple times it will queue the requests"   this is exactly what i want ,but the what is the way to call the intent service multiple times if not using a loop.thanks

Comment: Can't your WakefulBroadCastReceiver receiver just call onReceive() however many times you need the IntentService to do something ...

Comment: i think then i am wrong in understanding the docs, i thought that the onRecieve method will be called only once after every specific time period

Comment: It all depends on your code ... And how its set up .. Youve posted some generic code that doesn't show us the complete picture ... How does onReceive get called, and what you are doing in your intentService would clear  a lot of confusion up ..

Comment: i have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alarm manager to trigger the service is right way to do this. Why are you use for loop ?

Comment: i have 5 data sets in my local db that i want to send to server through intent service one after the other for that what i have done is that i query the local db and send an array to the intentservice class where i run the http commands in a for loop. but i dont know if it is the right way.

Comment: for that add for loop in your service and send it to server.